# how to capture URL as a variable and use it in the apache configuration file

Tags: linux, apache, http, centos, redhat

I would like to know how to set variable in centos apache config
The user will login as: www.example.com/$1 ($1 is a variable)

    ServerName  localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

## test1

Alias /$1 /home/client/$1

Options         Indexes FollowSymLinks
DAV             On
AllowOverRide   All
AuthType        Basic
AuthName        hellow
AuthUserFile    /etc/httpd/$1.password
Require         valid-user

How do I make this $1 to work

Answer (score 0):

DAVMinTimeout 180
 ServerName  localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

## test1

Alias /test1 /home/client/test1

Options         Indexes FollowSymLinks
DAV             On
AllowOverRide   All
AuthType        Basic
AuthName        Xfficient-test1
AuthUserFile    /etc/httpd/webDAV/test1.password
Require         valid-user